# snprintf issue when pass a macro

Tags: macros, null, arrays, printf

define a macro somewhere

```
    #define IDENTIFIER "identifier"
```

passing this macro into snprint()

```
    char buf[SIZE] = {0};
    if (snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%08X_%08X_%s.zip", i, j, IDENTIFIER) >= SIZE)
    {
        return "";
    }
```

however the result is:

```
    10800000_00000A00_(null).zip
```

I don't know why its value is '(null)'. as we know, the macro is stored in symbol table of compiler, maybe it needs a pointer or reference here.
could anyone explain this?

Comment: can you check the preprocessor output, and make sure the string is being substituted there?

Comment: What are the types of `i` and `j`?

Comment: does anyone know this issue? I'm waiting now.thanks

Comment: i, and j o's type is U32. those are ok.

Comment: the preprocessor could also be print.